# How to query on nested metadata with Docpad's query-engine

Tags: docpad, query-engine

As an example, I have a document with nested custom metadata like:

```
owner: {"id":"12345"}
```

I've tried to find this document with:

```
docpad.getCollection("documents").findAll({
    "owner.id": "12345"
});
```

but to no avail.

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nested queries aren't supported by default, as it is a tricky thing to do.

For now, you should be able to do this:

CoffeeScript:

```
docpad.getCollection("documents").findAll({
    "owner": ({id}) -> id is "12345"
})
```

JavaScript:

```
docpad.getCollection("documents").findAll({
    "owner": function(model){ return model.id === "12345" }
})
```